# controlar bucle while mediante booleanos

Tags: python, bucles

*(Creo que el título no es muy descriptivo pero no sé como ponerlo)*

Estoy analizando un vídeo frame a frame. La cosa es que el primer paso es coger ese frame y ver si es "trabajable". Esto se hace con la siguiente línea (empleando la librería `opencv`),

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

en `frame` guardamos la imagen actual con la que vamos a trabajar y en `ret` un booleano si esa imagen es procesable o no.

Por lo tanto yo lo que tengo es bucle un `while` que lo que hace es ir analizando frame a frame hasta el final de mi vídeo.

```
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame) #mostrar frame actual
```

¿Que sucede si ret es `Falso`? Pues que se genera un error. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto? Con un condicional que si es `Falso` rompa el bucle. **PERO** en este caso dejo de analizar el vídeo, es decir, si quedaban 20 frames por analizar, ya no los analizo por culpa de este defectuoso.

Entonces pensé, pues solo trabajo en los que el valor de `ret = True`, pero en ese caso, cuando viene un `ret = False` se genera un bucle infinito en ese frame defectuoso.

```
while (cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret ==  True:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame) #mostrar frame actual
```

Mi duda es, ¿cómo hago para que si un `ret` viene falso, simplemente paso al siguiente y sigo analizando hasta el final?

Gracias

Comment: Hola NEA no se si termino de entender el problema de tu código final, tal y como lo tienes, si `ret` es `False` el ciclo vuelve a iterar y se volvería a obtener otro frame. Para que se genere un ciclo infinito, `frame_func` tiene que estar generando frames "no procesables"  de forma continuada sin hacer que `isOpened` retorne `False`... De hecho, el ciclo solo sale cuando `isOpened` retorne False, no importa si los frames son o no buenos...

Comment: Buenas @FJSevilla yo pensaba lo mismo en cuanto si se obtenía un `False` pero precisamente pasa eso, que se me genera un bucle con justo ese frame no procesable, no pasa de él y por lo tanto se genera un bucle infinito en dicho frame.

Comment: ¿El video es finito?. Es decir, proviene de un archivo, no de una videocámara en tiempo real.

Comment: No,el vídeo está previamente grabado con la cam del ordenador. En concreto este dura 12 segs, y a los 8 muere...

Comment: NEA, he creado una respuesta, no se si solucionará tu problema porque no puedo probarlo ahora mismo un un archivo de video "deteriorado", comenta cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que el ciclo solo termina cuando cap e liberado, sin importar para nada el resto. En condiciones normales `ret` sería `False` cuando no quedan más frames que leer solamente, con lo que podrías romper el ciclo sin más en esta situación

Si este no es el caso (frames no pueden ser leídos antes del final del archivo pero quieres iterar sobre todos ellos), lo que puedes hacer es [obtener primero el número de frames del video](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704dadadc646b31cfd2194794a3a80b8fa6c2) e iterar solo las veces necesarias:

```
import cv2


file =  "ruta/video.avi"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
frame_count = 0

while cap.isOpened() and (frame_count < frames):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame_count += 1
    if ret:
        pass # Hacer lo que sea con el frame

cap.release()
```

O usando un `for` incluso:

```
import cv2


file =  "ruta/video.avi"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

for _ in range(int(frames)):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        pass # Hacer lo que sea con el frame
    else:
        if not cap.isOpened():
            break

cap.release()
```

Comment: Ya está solucionado, no era un problema de programación si no de mi reproductor, mil perdones. Con mi código ya va bien como es coherente y este también. ¿Debo ponerte la solución como correcta? MIL GRACIAS